# creating a if-elseif-else statement Zapier code

Tags: javascript, if-statement, zapier

Hello I’m trying to make an if then statement that checks some input data in the Zappy her JavaScript code block. And what i have is not working at the moment because I’m passing in `'Next Day'` and I’m not getting the date string for the following date. Would love any suggestions you have.

`const inputData = {'date': '2020-08-31T22:36:27Z', 'delivery': 'Next Day'};`

```
if (inputData.delivery == 'Next day') {
  const today = new Date(inputData.date)
  const tomorrow = new Date(today)
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
  const d = tomorrow
  output = {d}
} else if (inputData.delivery == 'Same Day') {
  const samedayoutput = inputData.date
  const d = samedayoutput
  output = {d}
} else {
  var d = new Date(inputData.date);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
  output = {d}
}
```

Comment: Saying something is "not working" is not a good way to phrase a question. *What* is not working? Is an error being thrown? Are you getting unexpected output - if so, please specify the input, what output is expected, and what output you are getting instead. Without knowing this we are in the dark as to what you consider "isn't working".

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```js
const inputData = {'date': '2020-08-31T22:36:27Z', 'delivery': 'Next Day'};

debugger;
if (inputData.delivery == 'Next Day') {
  const today = new Date(inputData.date)
  const tomorrow = new Date(today)
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
  const d = tomorrow
  output = {d}
} else if (inputData.delivery == 'Same Day') {
  const samedayoutput = inputData.date
  const d = samedayoutput
  output = {d}
} else {
  var d = new Date(inputData.date);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
  output = {d}
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i think its still not working properly because is sending the same date supplied and i need it to be the next day

Comment: @Luke You where checking for `== 'Next day'` but you should be checking for `== 'Next Day'`. I corrected it.